# How to hide Iron-Icon in gold-cc-cvc-input in Polymer?

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

Can anyone point me in the right direction of correctly hiding an iron-icon in a gold element? ([gold-cc-cvc-input](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/gold-cc-cvc-input))

[image]

I've tried the following and it didn't work:

```
<gold-cc-cvc-input style="iron-icon: display:none;" card-type="" name="cvc" id="cvcInput" auto-validate required ></gold-cc-cvc-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`--gold-cc-cvc-input-icon` mixin for the icon](https://github.com/PolymerElements/gold-cc-cvc-input/pull/40), but it's not yet released. The workaround is to set the icon's style imperatively. The icon IDs are `icon` and `amexIcon`, so you could do:

```
<gold-cc-cvc-input id="cvc"></gold-cc-cvc-input>

// <script>
attached: function() {
  this.$.cvc.$.icon.style.display = 'none';
  this.$.cvc.$.amexIcon.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/dNzzPM?editors=1010)

Comment: @RohitBanda No problem :)